# Forcing tab change to defined target

Tags: html, html-target

So I've read in a few places that we should limit usage of `target="_blank"` in favor of `target="somethingUnique"`, which is fine, and I agree with it.

Ex.

```
<form target="printer">
```

However I've run into a problem with it.

When I open something in a defined tab, and then I go back to the original tab and open something new in that same defined tab, my browser does not automatically re-open that tab. It simply loads the new content in the background and I have to manually switch tabs.

How can I force the tabs to switch automatically?

Comment: That is browser option you can't force users to a tab. People use popups to force content to your face, you can't move a user to a new tab unless their browser settings allow it.

Comment: @Khaltazar Even so, that is strictly a user-browser choice. My browser settings default to opening new tabs, so when I click a `target="_blank"` link, it opens in a new tab, and not in a pop-up window. Defining the target simply prevents the browser from opening an extra window/tab each and every time the user clicks the link; it reuses the same window.

Comment: Yes, you still can't force a tab to be switched to and even if you did that would be a security issue that would be patched eventually.